# gRPC+Go+React+TypeScript における Connect error

Tags: javascript, go, reactjs, typescript

### 概要

現在、勉強の為にgRPC+Go+React+TypeScriptを用いた個人開発を行っています。
ReactとGoの間にはEnvoy Proxyを置いています。
gRPCは初めてということもあり、新規会員登録機能においてgRPCの接続テストを行っています。
具体的には、新規会員登録機能にアクセスするとgRPCでリクエストを送り、それに対するレスポンスをReact側で`console.log`するというものです。
しかし、そこで下記の内容のエラーが発生しました。
自分なりに色々調べてみましたが、解決せず…。
このままだと一向に次のフェーズに進めそうにないです…。
どなたか解決方法のご教授お願い致します。

### エラーの内容

```
Error: upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination
```

### 該当のソースコード

```
// client

FROM  node:latest

WORKDIR /HEW2020/client
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --ignore-engines --network-timeout 1000000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

```
// server

FROM golang:1.12

ENV GO111MODULE=on

WORKDIR /go/src/HEW2020/server
COPY . .
RUN go get github.com/pilu/fresh
CMD ["fresh"]
EXPOSE 49200 49201
```

```
// envoy

FROM  envoyproxy/envoy:v1.12.2
WORKDIR /HEW2020/proxy
COPY ./envoy.yaml .
CMD /usr/local/bin/envoy -c /HEW2020/proxy/envoy.yaml
EXPOSE 8080
```

```
// docker-compose.yml

version: "3"

services:
  proxy:
    build: ./proxy
    volumes:
      - ./proxy:/HEW2020/proxy
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - "server"
    container_name: "hew2020-proxy"

  server:
    build: ./server
    volumes:
      - ./server:/go/src/HEW2020/server
    ports:
      - "49200:49200"
    container_name: "hew2020-server"

  client:
    build: ./client
    volumes:
      - ./client:/HEW2020/client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    container_name: "hew2020-client"

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ../mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ../mysql/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
      - ../mysql/initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: hew2020
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      # TZ: 'Asia/Tokyo'
    ports:
      - "13306:3306"
    container_name: hew2020-db
```

```
// envoy.yaml

admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        # 全IPの8080PortでListen
        socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 8080 }
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
              config:
                codec_type: auto
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service
                      domains: ["*"]
                      routes:
                        - match: { prefix: "/" }
                          route:
                            cluster: web_app_service
                            max_grpc_timeout: 0s
                      cors:
                        allow_origin:
                          - "*"
                        allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                        allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                        max_age: "1728000"
                        expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.grpc_web
                  - name: envoy.cors
                  - name: envoy.router
  clusters:
    - name: web_app_service
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: logical_dns
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      upstream_connection_options:
        tcp_keepalive:
          keepalive_time: 300
      lb_policy: round_robin
      # win/mac hosts: Use address: host.docker.internal instead of address: localhost in the line below
      hosts:
        [
          {
            socket_address:
              { address: host.docker.internal, port_value: 49200 },
          },
        ]
```

```js
// Signup.tsx

import { SexTypes } from "../../proto/enums_pb"
import { SignUpRequest } from "../../proto/messages_pb"
import { WebAppServiceClient } from "../../proto/web_app_service_pb_service"

const Signup: React.FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  useEffect(() => {
    const req = new SignUpRequest()
    req.setName("MyName")
    req.setSex(SexTypes.SEX_MALE)
    req.setAge(22)
    req.setUserId("abcdefg")
    req.setUserPw("password")

    const client = new WebAppServiceClient("http://localhost:8080", {})
    client.signUp(req, (err, res) => {
      if (err || res === null) {
        throw err
      }
      console.log(res.getMessage())
    })
  })
  return (
    <Root>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <h1>Signup</h1>
      <h1>Signup</h1>
      <h1>Signup</h1>
    </Root>
  )
}
```

```
// web_app_service.proto

web_app_service_proto
service WebAppService {
    rpc SignUp (messages.SignUpRequest) returns (messages.AuthResponse) {}
}
```

```
// messages.proto

message AuthResponse {
    bool status = 1;
    enums.StatusCodes status_code = 2;
    string token = 3;
}
message SignUpRequest {
    string name  = 1;
    enums.SexTypes sex = 2;
    uint32 age = 3;
    string user_id = 4;
    string user_pw = 5;
}
```

### 追記

公式サイト([該当ページ](https://www.envoyproxy.io/learn/backpressure))をチェックしてみたところ下記の様な記述がありました。

```
Two quick definitions, used by Envoy:

Upstream connections are the service Envoy is initiating the connection to.
Downstream connections are the client that is initiating a request through Envoy.
```

```
Upstream Connection Closed
What it is: When the upstream closes the connection before the response is finished sending, Envoy cannot send a complete response to the downstream.

Result: This depends on whether the downstream has started receiving data.

If it has not (i.e. the upstream disconnects quickly), the downstream connection is reset.
If it has, the downstream receives an HTTP 503 and the body text “upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers”
```

これはUpstream（つまりGo）側に問題があるということでしょうか？

Comment: レスポンスが返らずにコネクションが切断されてしまうという事は、golang で書かれたサーバプログラムで panic が発生(異常終了)しているのではないでしょうか。syslog などにエラーメッセージが記録されているかもしれませんが、log パッケージを利用してエラーメッセージをファイルに出力する様にしておくと原因究明の手掛かりが得られるかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go側でエラーが発生していました…。修正したところ無事解決いたしました。
ありがとうございました！